# UnicodeEncodeError:'charmap' with 'Ö','Ç' etc

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I connect to MySQL and retrieve usernames containing 'Ö', 'ğ', 'Ş', etc.
It works fine with MySQL or PHP but in Python 2.6.8, an error occur.
Here is my code:

```python
#C:\Python27\Lib\encodings
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

conn = MySQLdb.Connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="mypass", db="mydb", charset="utf8", init_command="SET NAMES UTF8")
cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("select * from users");
tmpDict=cursor.fetchallDict()
print tmpDict[0]['NAME'].decode('utf8')
```

I expect 'Ömer Şirin' here but instead I get the following error:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd6' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to decode('utf8')

Comment: Can you `print repr(tmpDict[0]['NAME'])`?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan result=None

Comment: @RitobrotoMukherjee I want decode nothing just get my strings correct

Comment: Curious, is that what you got when you replaced `print tmpDict[0]['NAME'].decode('utf8')`? Or did you put that line of code somewhere else?

Comment: Does setting locale as demonstrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347772/print-unicode-string-in-python-regardless-of-environment help you?

Comment: Also, I think it should be .encode('utf-8') from Unicode, not the other way. If result is in utf-8, you do not need to encode or decode anything.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan 'UnicodeEncodeError'...

Comment: @RomanSusi Smilar stiation.. but cant solve with most voted answer. I think the problem is python file encoding is 'ascii' my data is already utf8 yeah but some utf8 characters not in range of ascii

Comment: @MehmetYenerYILMAZ: what happens if you add three lines: `print type(tmpDict[0]['NAME'])` `print repr(tmpDict[0]['NAME'])`  `print u'\xd6'` to the code and copy-paste the results **literally** (it is possible that `repr()` is `result=None` but it is *very* unusual).

Comment: The problem might be related to the output operation, not the retrieval from the DB, and there are hundreds of postings here discussing this. That said, why are you using an ancient Python 2 versions instead of a recent Python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *two* errors and two issues:

1. UnicodeEncodeError:'charmap' with 'Ö','Ç' etc
2. 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd6' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

If `type(tmpDict[0]['NAME']) == unicode` then the second issue can be reproduced easily:

```
>>> u'\xd6'.decode('utf-8') #XXX BROKEN, DO NOT DO IT!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd6' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What happens is that `u'\xd6'` is already a Unicode string and therefore before decoding it, it has to be converted to bytes first and Python uses the default encoding (`'ascii'`) to do it. The correct solution is to *drop `.decode('utf-8')`* -- **do not decode Unicode** strings (it is fixed in Python 3, you get `AttributeError` there if you try to decode a Unicode string).

The first issue *"UnicodeEncodeError:'charmap'"* is likely due to printing Unicode to Windows console. To reproduce, run `print u'\xd6'`. To fix it, [install `win-unicode-console`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/4279).

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL driver automatically decodes UTF-8 strings into Python Unicode objects.

You should be able to prove this with:

```
>>> type(tmpDict[0]['NAME'])
<type 'unicode'>
```

You should be able to print `tmpDict[0]['NAME']` straight to the console. If you still have problems printing, lookup the exception in StackOverflow again